# MySQL DateTime Fraction/Microsecond issue

Tags: mysql, django, datetime

I'm wondering if there's any MySQL setting you can set, so when you have a datetime coulmn with no fraction (datetime(0)), but you query it with a fraction (ie '2015-01-01 22:22:22.123000') it will still match (removing the fraction part)
The current behaviour is giving me some issues, since the application send queries with microseconds, but I don't want to use microseconds on mysql columns (Or otherwise, I need to convert all existing datetime columns to datetime(6), using additional storage for something I don't even need)

Comment: So... any query with microseconds... you want it not to match? (Actually, it's a little bit surprising if it does match).  What about `WHERE column_name = CAST('2015-01-01 22:22:22.123000' AS DATETIME)`? Not sure that would make a difference but it might change the apparent cast from implicit to explicit.  Or... `WHERE column_name = TIMESTAMP '2015-01-01 22:22:22.123000'`

Comment: I would want my queries that HAVE microseconds, to still match datetime columns that are defined as DATETIME(0). So if my column has a value of '2015-01-01 22:22:22' but my WHERE is = '2015-01-01 22:22:22.123000' it would still match. MySQL should automatically remove the microseconds since the column is defined as no microseconds, but it doesn't, and so the query does not match (and I want it to match)

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: Apologies, but I misinterpreted the question initially, transposing the observed and desired behaviors.  The actual observed behavior being reported here makes more sense, now, though the desired behavior expressed here -- trying to persuade the server to truncate a value and do extra sloppy equality comparisons on datetimes by default -- seems somewhat misguided.

Comment: MySQL 5.6.20
Imo is not misguided, because if you send a date it truncates it without telling you anything and returning okay, but if you try to retrieve the exact same value you just inserted, it fails, because the truncation only happens in one operation, so for me it is actually inconsistent, it should behave the same on all operations.

Comment: Just to add to my previous answer, on mysql 5.5, the behaviour is the one I want (because there's no fraction support at all for columns, yet functions support it)